# How to get a nofication when post submitted

Tags: posts, customization, admin, notifications

I was wondering is there a way to send the admin a notification (email or otherwise) whenever a user submits a post.

Currently, I have to log into the admin section to see if there was anything submitted. I need to review their post before actually publishing it, so I need to be notified via email whenever a post is submitted.

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this inside your themes functions.php:

its a function by dagon design

```
function dddn_process($id) {

global $wpdb;

$tp = $wpdb->prefix;

$result = $wpdb->get_row("
    SELECT post_status, post_title, user_login, user_nicename, display_name
    FROM {$tp}posts, {$tp}users
    WHERE {$tp}posts.post_author = {$tp}users.ID
    AND {$tp}posts.ID = '$id'
");

if ($result->post_status == "publish") {

    $message = "";
    $message .= "A new post was submitted on '" . get_bloginfo('name') . "'\n\n";
    $message .= "Title: " . $result->post_title . "\n\n";


    $message .= "Author: " . $result->display_name . "\n\n";

    $message .= "Link: " . get_permalink($id);

    $subject = "Post Submitted on '" . get_bloginfo('name') . "'";

    $recipient = get_bloginfo('admin_email');

    mail($recipient, $subject, $message);

}

}

add_action('publish_post', 'dddn_process');
```

Comment: It works! What would I set post_status for published posts instead of pending?

Comment: changing `if ($result->post_status == "pending") {
` to `if ($result->post_status == "publish") {
` should do it..

Comment: Marin, I "publish" but it didn't send the email...

Comment: Have edited my original post with the changes, try that big block of code again, have added a little to it regarding the action hook